# C# Move the positon of Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to create an input and an output section in a Console application. I need the finished result to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH6G0.jpg

How would I go about creating this or is it even possible ? And this is required to be a Console application. Also, how would I go about clearing the area where the Console.ReadLine() is ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible, you can Set the CursorPosition to anywhere on the screen, then set it back to the bottom for input

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowLeft, Console.WindowBottom);
```

possibly -1 on the bottom

You might also want to have a look at https://github.com/AnthonyMastrean/ConsoleEx

Comment: Ah thank you, I'll try this in a moment, one thing I forgot to mention was, how would I go about clearing that area ?

Comment: if you can put the cursor anywhere and write anything anywhere, I'm sure you can work out how to clear things :)

Comment: you might also want to play with `Console.ForegroundColor` and  `Console.BackgroundColor`

Comment: Thanks :D. Also I'm using multithreading to read and write at the same time, would it still function properly ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean I should create a function to write everything depending on the area specified or ...?

Comment: Just been reading about it, and I can't seem to find any examples using a Dispatcher in a Console applications. Sorry for the amount of questions, never even heard of a Dispatcher before, nor have I really made Console applications. Do you know of any decent examples ?

Comment: Console is (mostly?) thread-safe class, you can safely use Read/Write methods from background threads without synchronization.

Comment: @PTwr the goal is to have ReadLine at the bottom, whilst also having WriteLine at the top.

Comment: @Ptwr Threadsafe doesn't mean that a sequence of related statements are magically made atomic. Some serialisation is clearly needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is somewhat incorrect. You lack experience with operating ye old DOS console and got fixated on using build-in functions forgetting that Console is stream-based and can be operated manually.

The moment you need to implement your own text input layout you need to ditch built-in line-reading methods and switch to manual stream operations. Thankfully .NET makes things easier than it was in ye old flat COM's.

For example you can start with following code that moves text input and manages output to five lines. Of course it is far from perfect (infinite loop... static variables... ugh shame on me) but I'll leave it in raw form to make it simpler.

In order to turn it into multithread application you will need to make "output" thread-safe (there are many ways to do it) and change content of Foo() (currently it is just echo).

```
class Program
{
    static List<string> output = new List<string>();
    static int maxlines = 5;
    static void Foo(string s)
    {
        // echo
        output.Add(s);
        while (output.Count>maxlines)
        {
            output.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "";
        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                char c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '\r': Foo(s); s = ""; break;
                    case '\b': if (s.Length > 0) { s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1); } break;
                    default: s += c; break;
                }
                // some clearing
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowLeft, 6);
                Console.Write("                                                                 ");
                // and write current "buffer"
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowLeft, 6);
                Console.Write(s);
            }
            // now lets handle our "output stream"
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(maxlines, output.Count); i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowLeft, i);
                Console.Write(output[i].PadRight(32));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me being an idiot or what, but how would I implement ReadLine into this, as this just seems to be focused on outputting, which I can do quite easily with the standard Methods provided.

Comment: Foo() method can be considered ReadLine, it is called after enter is pressed and its parameter is input from user. To use this example you will need to pass it input to processing block. In short, it is event based input system.